# Cannot see shared folder in Windows Server 2012 connecting with Remmina in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, shared-directory

I connect from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS via VirtualBox, then from Ubuntu I connect to Windows Server 2012 via Remmina.

I've configured Remmina to connect with shared folder but I don't know how to see that shared folder in Windows Server 2012, maybe adding a network location, but when I'm asked for the network address I don't know what I have to write.

Is this way correct? What did I miss?

Answer (score 10):

Well, I really don't understand why, but if you configure in remmina sound to "local" (on advance configuration), it works.

See: https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/issues/243

Comment: Yes, it really works and does not require to install any ppa, great.

Comment: Remmina next didn't work on my XFCE Mint 17.3 machine (based on 14.04), so I reverted the version that's in the repository. File sharing didn't work until I made the sound be set to local.

Answer (score 10):

The versions of Remmina and the FreeRDP library it relies on that come with Ubuntu 14.04 are a bit outdated now. Thankfully there's a PPA for the latest Remmina which makes updating quite easy:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfreerdp-plugins-standard remmina remmina-plugin-rdp
```

After updating make sure you fully close any running copies of Remmina by selecting *Quit* from the tray icon, and then reopen it.

Comment: Can confirm it working for `14.04`and `15.10`. Make sure to first close remmina (right click the icon an quit).

Comment: Good point, I actually ran into that myself, where I was running the old version even after upgrading.